# Disable sound permanently in Windows 7 and Windows 8 (all types of sound e.g. application sound, theme sound, beep)

Tags: windows-7, audio

I want to disable all types of sounds permanently so the user will not be able to hear any kind of sound in future.

I have uninstalled sound drivers from Device Manager, but on restarting PC they get automatically installed again.

Comment: What about rebooting the machine and listening to the POST beeps? Do you want them to occur? To get rid of that you need to pull out system's little speaker. For all the other sounds you need to disable Audio Devices in Device Manager.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the speakers from the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Disable the soundcard in the motherboard BIOS.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU! Please include some more information on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete the drivers, Disable them instead. They stay installed but not used. Right click on the sound devices and select disable - They should all be under 'Sound, Video and Game controllers' (Windows 7/8)