# Way to disable sound (drivers) Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

I am wanting to have no available sound outputs in windows10. IE no way to play sound, simply disabling the drivers does not cause them to unload immediately for some reason, still puzzling out why. Also a way to turn it all on again.

Similar to [Disable sound permanently in Windows 7 and Windows 8 (all types of sound e.g. application sound, theme sound, beep)](https://superuser.com/questions/569993/disable-sound-permanently-in-windows-7-and-windows-8-all-types-of-sound-e-g-ap) , but in my case, no smart answers are needed, and I need to be able to do this without a reboot/power cycle most preferably. Sorry for sounding hypothetical? Yes, I did not share context, but the context is checking that an app can know if you have a way to play sound, since when you cannot, the app needs to provide the user with feedback and an alternative content if possible. Other ways too, than disabling devices are welcome. I am a software tester, hence my question, so any way to do so that could be conceivably scriptable would be doing my homework for me, if it does exist.

Comment: There is no purpose in doing this, it can be accomplished in other ways, we do not answer hypothetical questions.

Comment: Other ways, which are not obvious. I am wanting to verify that an application can detect whether you have sound hardware or not, correctly. I could have 2 computers, or 2 virtual machines, or get an answer to my question. My question is Hypothetical @Moab

Comment: `net stop audiosrv` stops the Windows audio service.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work, was to disable the sound controllers, not the devices (speakers). I found that like others who tried before me, disabling the output drivers(devices) had no effect anymore after a reboot. But disabling the controller drivers themselves does work. On my system, disabling them required a reboot, which is inconvenient, mileage may vary based on environment.

[image]

Disabling the controllers (highlight green) was the thing that worked, but did require a reboot, enabling them did not require reboot. The devices in yellow did not have the desired effect.

Comment: exactly how you did this with screenshots would be nice, thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with screenies on stack, so added a linky :-)